# Can't get widths of divs to align

Tags: html, css, layout

On this page (http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hiking_group.php?hiking_group_id=2), I'm trying to get on the right side, to have the button for "join group" to

1. Have the same botder width as the div above it
2. Leave at least a little white space before the ad that comes right below it

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<div style="width: 285px; float: right; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">
```

But adding the padding just made the div wider, and didn't make any space to the bottom.

Any idea what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use inline styles.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the button be centered vertically inside the border?

Comment: Try using this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/HUAwL/

Comment: Here is a good article to read up on for centering things: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do margin-bottom instead of padding-bottom

Comment: Thank you - that fixed the bottom.  What about aligning it to be the same width with the div above?